# The use of React Native Cards with ListItem

Tags: react-native

I have been working on code that displays an array with 4 people that have name, description and image. I am using it with a Card, ListItem and FlatList. I have somehow managed to display something but my problem is this information stored in this array is displayed single card, i.e each card having Card title, name, description and image but what I want is  to display all 4 items in the array in **one single card** that is my intention instead of having separate cards in each item of this array. Can anyone help guide how I can display all 4 item in one single card ?. below is my code:

Also if I want style the "title" item in the ListItem, How do i do that?

AboutComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import { FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native' ;
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { LEADERS } from '../shared/leaders';


function RenderLeader(props) {
    //get the leaders array
    const leaders = props.leaders;

    const renderLeaderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
            <Card title="Corporate Leadership" >
            {
                <ListItem   
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    subtitle={item.description}
                    //hideChevron={true}         
                    leftAvatar={{source: require('./images/jack.png') }}
                        />
            }
          </Card>
        )
    }
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data= {leaders}
            renderItem={renderLeaderItem}
            keyExtractor={Item => Item.id.toString() }
            />
        )
}

class About extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            leaders : LEADERS,
            history: HistoryElement
        }
    }

    //setup the navigation for the current class [Dishdetail]
    static navigationOptions = {
        title : 'About'
    }

    render(){
       return (
        <>
           <History history={this.state.history} />
           <RenderLeader leaders={this.state.leaders} />    
        </>
       )
    }
}

export default About;
```

Comment: So you want to have a list inside the card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wrap the flatlist inside a card instead of wrapping the listitem inside the card, which will give you the expected output.
And the card title can be styled using the titleStyle prop of card. You can see the full code below.

```
function RenderLeader(props) {
  //get the leaders array
  const leaders = props.leaders;

  const renderLeaderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        key={index}
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.description}
        //hideChevron={true}
        leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/jack.png') }}
      />
    );
  };
  return (
    <Card title="Corporate Leadership" titleStyle={{color:'red'}}>
      <FlatList
        data={leaders}
        renderItem={renderLeaderItem}
        keyExtractor={(Item) => Item.id.toString()}
      />
    </Card>
  );
}
```